# SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService with Selenium Grid on Ubuntu failing to drive Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I fail to drive Firefox from Selenium with geckodriver. This is odd, because chrome is driven with same framework without errors!

These are my Version numbers:

```
Firefox 54.0 (64-bit)
Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar
client-combined-3.5.3-nodeps.jar

geckodriver-v0.19.1-linux64
chromedriver_linux64 

Ubuntu 16.10
```

The error I get from Selenium webdriver with java is the following:

```
--------------------------------Error:
leder@leder-VirtualBox:~/Source/SeleniumCheese/bin$ ./execute_grid.sh 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: host: 'leder-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.0-59-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 1.39 seconds
---------------------------------Schnapp
```

This is my setup, where firefox is broken and chrome is OK:

Grid_SetUp.java

```
package de.auticon.selenium_server;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.By;   
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;   
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;    
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;    
import java.net.URL;

public class Grid_SetUp {   
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[]  args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{   
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/opt/selenium/chromedriver");    
        String URL = "http://www.google.de";    
        String Node = "http://192.168.40.40:4444/wd/hub";    
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();   
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
        driver.navigate().to(URL);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        //Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();
        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.quit();    
    }    
}
```

selenium_grid.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -role hub &
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/selenium/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.40.40:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig /opt/selenium/defaultNodeConfig.json -browser "browserName=firefox,platform=LINUX" &
```

execute_grid.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp ".:/opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar" de.auticon.selenium_server.Grid_SetUp
```

---

I updated the question for working configuration now. But when running the firefox Selenium TC the TC completes, unfortunately the server ends with an error message "session not created":

```
13:49:10.376 INFO - Removing session org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@70c81601
13:49:10.381 INFO - To downstream: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Tried to run command without establishing a connection","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\n   0:           0x4edb3c - backtrace::backtrace::trace::hc4bd56a2f176de7e\n   1:           0x4edb72 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he3b2a15d39027c46\n   2:           0x4409a1 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h81babdd86c977032\n   3:           0x4280ea - <webdriver::server::Dispatcher<T, U>>::run::h2119c674d7b88193\n   4:           0x4029b9 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h21d98a9ff86d4c25\n   5:           0x40be65 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h5cff0c9b18cfdbba\n   6:           0x5e6a6c - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic\n                        at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:99\n   7:           0x41eb22 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h413eb1d9d9f1c473\n   8:           0x5df13b - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>\n                        at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:692\n                         - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread\n                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21\n                         - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start\n                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84"}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few words about `Selenium Grid` Configuration:

- You mentioned your `Test Bed` as `selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar` and `client-combined-3.5.3-nodeps.jar`. As per `Best Practices`, you should use either of the following **not both**
- Always try to use the latest released version i.e. **`selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar`**
- In **`selenium_grid.sh:`** you need to change the following :

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/selenium/geckodriver
  ```

Comment: Thank you, DebanjanB! I can leave out `:/opt/selenium/client-combined-3.5.3-nodeps.jar` without a problem and `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/selenium/geckodriver` is running fine now!

Comment: I updated the question to the working configuration and added a new error message, please have a look.

Comment: @DebanjanB based on https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/, the latest version is 3.141.59, i use that but does not make help.

Answer (score 0):

I simply follow this code using my firefox browser, seleinum grid with Testng in eclipse

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\FireFoxDriver\\geckodriver.exe");    
    String URL = "http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html";    
    String Node = "http://192.168.43.97:4444/wd/hub";    
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();   
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.close();
```

For creating hub in your local machine
java -jar E:\SeleniumGrid\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub

open cmd and enter above line where your selenium standalone server is downloaded
Then you will get these two

Nodes should register to http://192.168.43.97:4444/grid/register/
Clients should connect to http://192.168.43.97:4444/wd/hub

Then again open cmd and type this for node
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="E:\FireFoxDriver\geckodriver.exe" -jar E:\SeleniumGrid\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.43.97:4444/grid/register