# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run a test on Remote Machine for selenium Grid and it gives me expection erro

Expection

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
```

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String nodeURL;
        String baseURL;
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY,new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe").getAbsolutePath());
 WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.132.48.16:5566/wd/hub"),capabilities );


        driver.get("http://google.com");
           System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Comment: could you please confirm your firefox version and geckodriver version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService with Selenium Grid on Ubuntu failing to drive Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551116/selenium-grid-on-ubuntu-failing-to-drive-firefox)